# Detached garage sub-panel issues for older house

Tags: garage, subpanel

I have an older house (1930) and there is an old sub-panel in the garage (with two of those old glass fuses and a knife switch).  The garage is fed underground with 120V by two #10 wires from a 30 amp  breaker in the house. There is no grounding rod at the garage location. Is it okay as is?
I think at least I should add a 6 ft ground rod, else the grounds of the three re-wired garage circuits have no place to go (not safe, since not grounded). That ground would, I think, not be connected to the neutral wire. Do I need two ground rods?
I was also thinking of replacing the old panel with a modern panel with a 30 amp main breaker feeding the three circuits. Would I be getting into trouble by this upgrade? That is, would I be required to replace the wires feeding the detached garage (with 3 or 4 wires)?
If I replace the old sub-panel, should its main breaker be a GFI, or should the feeding breaker in the house be GFI?
Advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you currently have 2 hots or 1 hot + 1 neutral? Do the wires travel inside a metal conduit between the buildings? Can you upload a picture of the subpanel?

Comment: Is the existing cable to the garage directly buried in the ground, run in a conduit for its whole length, or run as overhead wiring?

Comment: Currently have 1 hot and 1 neutral. Inside the garage, the wires are in a metal conduit entering the ground through the garage's cement floor, so I can guess they continue that way underground to the house (perhaps a 40 ft run). They enter the house through a 10" thick concrete wall, below ground level. I will obtain a photo and post it, hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: If they are in metal conduit all the way (likely, for that age buried service) you **have** a grounding conductor (the metal conduit) if it's properly connected to metal electrical equipment at both ends.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Of course I have a ground via the metal conduit. I will check that it goes all the way back to the main panel. I think it does. DO I NEED ONE OR MORE GROUND RODS AT THE GARAGE?

Comment: Also, I wonder if I need a GFI breaker at the main panel and/or the sub-panel.